# A FindRoot error

Tags: equation-solving

```
f[k_] = {{0.001 - 2 I k + 0.001 k^2, -0.001, 0.001, -0.001}, {-1, 
0.5 - I k + 0.001 k^2, 0.501, -0.001}, {0.001, -0.001, 0.001 + 2 I k + 0.001 k^2, -0.001}, {0.501, -0.001, -1, 0.5 + I k + 0.001 k^2}};

r[k_] := Sort[Eigenvalues[f[k]], Im[#1] > Im[#2] &][[4]];

Plot[Re[r[k]], {k, -1, 1}]

FindRoot[Re[r[k]], {k, 1}]
```

Cannot get why does `FindRoot` give the error `FindRoot::lstol`. The plotted graph shows that there is a real $k$ for which $\Re\ r(k)$ becomes $0$.
Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, if we take the conjugate of this eigenvalue (the first element in the sorted list) which has the same real part then $FindRoot$ works fine...

Comment: Define instead so the function only accepts explicit `NumberQ` input. That is, `Clear[r]
r[k_?NumberQ] := Sort[Eigenvalues[f[k]], Im[#1] > Im[#2] &][[4]];`. This way `FindRoot` is less likely to get frisky and move away from the nearby root. (I blame preprocessing for the funny behavior. Preprocessing, and bad parenting.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I asked my kids and they assured me that it's the first option. However they aren't completely sure about how hard a preprocessor could kick.

Comment: @belisarius He used to be an Argentinian soccer player. Preprocessing for `FindRoot` is just a retirement job. And he's polite and all that. But he has the unfortunate habit of booting points out of their attraction zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Daniel Lichtblau, restrict definition of r[k_] to numeric arguments, i.e., r[k_?NumericQ]

```
f[k_] = {{0.001 - 2 I k + 0.001 k^2, -0.001, 0.001, -0.001}, {-1, 
     0.5 - I k + 0.001 k^2, 0.501, -0.001}, {0.001, -0.001, 
     0.001 + 2 I k + 0.001 k^2, -0.001}, {0.501, -0.001, -1, 
     0.5 + I k + 0.001 k^2}} // Rationalize;

r[k_?NumericQ] := Sort[Eigenvalues[f[k]], Im[#1] > Im[#2] &][[4]];

Plot[Re[r[k]], {k, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-0.0005, 0.0005}]

FindRoot[Re[r[k]], {k, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] & /@ {-0.4, 0, 0.4} // Chop
```

[image]